# Pygments/minted highlight environment name in bold

Tags: minted, pygments

Is it possible to adapt `minted` or Pygments to also highlight names of environments? I would like to have this output

[image]

But all I get is this

[image]

I.e. `{itemize}` is not bold. I guess it is possible by changing the Latex lever or something like that, but I have no idea where to start.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[parskip = full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{minted}

\usemintedstyle{bw}

\begin{document}

This input code

\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{itemize}[label = {--}]% comment
   \item Text
\end{itemize}
\end{minted}

should result in an output like from the following code

\ttfamily
\textbf{\textbackslash begin\{itemize\}}[label = \{-\/-\}]\textit{\% comment}\\
\strut\ \strut\ \strut\ \textbf{\textbackslash item} Text\\
\textbf{\textbackslash end\{itemize\}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `listing` package may do the job as well : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings but I guess it won't be a good enough workaround? It seems hard coded in `minted`.

Comment: The problem with `listings` is that it only highlights known keywords and doesn’t automatically recognises all macros starting with a backslash … and I don’t want to take care of a manually edited long list of macros ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `minted` relies exclusively on Pygments to process the input code. [The documentation itself](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) doesn't reference ways to alter the content of the output from `minted` directly. The remaining solution is to use a custom Pygments lexer. That's quite well documented there: http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment. I'll give a step-by-step solution in case someone else wants to customize lexers.

## Find how Pygments processes LaTeX input

Go to the `lexers` folder in the Pygments installation folder. In my case, on Windows, it's in `<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/pygments/lexers/`; on macOS it is something like `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Pygments-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/pygments/lexers/`. I haven't tried on Linux. You'll find the path for every lexer in the `_mapping.py` file.

For [TeX/LaTeX](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/lexers/_mapping.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#_mapping.py-411), it's the `TexLexer` class, inside [`markup.py`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/lexers/markup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#markup.py-277).

Let's see how it processes a `\begin{itemize}`. The main "state" is `root`. When the program finds a `\` followed by one or more letters ([l. 298](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/lexers/markup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#markup.py-298)), it treats all of it as a `Keyword` (In our case, that's the `\` + `begin`, that will be printed in bold.), then parses the rest in the `command` state. The `command` state checks for square brackets or a star, but doesn't handle curly braces. The `{itemize}` will then be parsed back in the `root` state, where it will be printed as a simple text.

## Create a custom lexer

If I understood the question correctly, all that's needed is to parse `\begin` and `\end` differently than the other commands. Let's create a custom TeX lexer that inherits from the original `TexLexer` and adds those two specific matches in the `root` state.

This is what I wrote, in a new Python file. I'm not detailing all of it since it's very context-specific, and the official documentation is precise (see for example [here](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment#subclassing-lexers-derived-from-regexlexer) regarding the inheritance).

```
from pygments.lexer import inherit
from pygments.token import Keyword
from pygments.lexers.markup import TexLexer

__all__ = ['CustomTexLexer']

class CustomTexLexer(TexLexer):
    aliases = ['xtex', 'xlatex']

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r'\\begin\{[a-zA-Z\*]+\}', Keyword, 'command'),
            (r'\\end\{[a-zA-Z\*]+\}', Keyword),
            inherit,
        ],
    }
```

It might also be possible to add it to the same file as `TexLexer`, but I'm not sure how safe it is. In both case, you need to give new `aliases` and add the class name to `__all__`.

## Rebuild the lexer mapping

The documentation says to build using this command:

```
$ make mapfiles
```

but I couldn't find the corresponding Makefile. The documentation might be outdated here, since the `_mapping.py` file has been made into a script that can update itself:

```
$ python _mapping.py
```

(On macOS this must be executed as `sudo` to grant writing access in the `/Library/` tree.)

## Result

We now have two LaTeX lexers at our disposal:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}

\begin{document}

Original lexer:
\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{itemize}[label = {--}]% comment
   \item Text
\end{itemize}
\end{minted}

Custom lexer:
\begin{minted}{xlatex}
\begin{itemize}[label = {--}]% comment
   \item Text
\end{itemize}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

(I had to simplify the preamble because of technical issues, it's unrelated to the current question.)

Output:

[image: Output with both original and custom lexers]

## Minor update

I updated the custom lexer so that it processes optional arguments of an environment the same way as optional arguments of a macro. It sounded more appropriate at this point. Note that it makes zero difference in the MWE, since the `bw` class doesn't emphasize the related object, `Name.Attribute`. Just for show, this is what it looks like with the default style:

[image: Updated output]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply … Thank your _very_ much for you effort and the detailed answer! It works like charm `:-)` I took the liberty to edit the macOS paths to you answer. Further more I added `\*` to the environment name RegEx.

Comment: @Tobi No problem, thanks for the precisions! Glad I could help.